ID an alien movie where we are the alien?
In 2000++ I watched this movie. 
I remember a scene where the human turns out to be the alien. The humans visit another planet. The alien planet is Earth-like. 
The story is first told from the alien's POV (The viewer thinks the inhabitant is the human, and the human is alien visiting the planet). Then in the last part, it's revealed that the inhabitant is the alien, and the alien visiting the planet is the human.
It's translated to my language so I don't know the original language. Probably low budget. 
I think is not a Hollywood movie, not animated (can't find it in IMDB) but the actors are European/American. 

What is "your language"? It may help to figure out which movie it is based on which languages it was translated into. Also, do you remember if it was in color or black and white and an approximate guess of the age of the movie?

It looks like The Invaders, The Twilight Zone, S2E15 (1961). IMDb extract:

An old woman who lives alone in a ramshackle farm house comes face to face with alien invaders. She hears something on her roof and then finds a flying saucer, perhaps six or seven feet across from which emerges two small robots. She fights them as best she can and eventually succeeds in destroying their ship. The nature of the invaders however is not immediately obvious however.

Except that it’s not a movie, this fits your description.
Here is the trailer:




I haven't check it out but the movie I'm looking for is in color. and I think not that old
